# Adding Max Wallet Limit but exclude creator wallet and liquidity pools ERC20 Simple Code

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, wallets, liquidity

As stated, looking to do a very simple clean ERC-20 contract with basic functionality. Only thing I want to add is a max wallet limit of 2% to avoid sniping bots or whales buying at once.

Only issue I faced before is the contract sometimes fails when I try to deploy the tokens to the creator address. When I got this resolved (using a pre-made script), I wasn't able to add more than 2% into any liquidity pool. Any guidance on what to add to introduce the max wallet limit excluding creator and liquidity pools, or another solution to bypass this? I want to do 60% of the tokens at least in LP, creator will end up holding about 20% and rest will be airdropped.

This is the code i'm writing for my simple contract on Remix (without max wallet function)

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Website | https://web.site
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MYTOKEN is ERC20 {
    
    constructor() ERC20("My Token", "MINE") {

     _mint(msg.sender, 123000 * 10**18);
    }

}
```